# Use the Windows 8 Bootloader for dual boot instead of GRUB

Tags: dual-boot

Okay so this has been a goal almost a year now. I still haven't figured out so I am just going to finally ask this question.

Here are things I am sure you need to know:

- My computer - ATIV Book 8
- Runs Ubuntu 14.04.1 and Windows 8.1 Pro
- Came preinstalled with Windows 8 so I it is UEFI based

So I have tried using EasyBCD 2.2 but I have had TERRIBLE exp with it. I added the entry in and everything but it still wants to boot Grub before the Windows bootloader. Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm sure one of you guys know what to do hopefully. :/

EDIT: OK so if I boot the computer I get this windows 7 Bootloader with Ubuntu that doesn't work. If I boot windows and hold the shift key I get the the Windows 8 boot menu but Ubuntu doesn't work still. 
Buuuut if I go to "use a device" and pick Ubuntu, it will boot up Ubuntu.

I'm soooooo confused why the the entry doesn't work and why I get this windows 7 bootloader.

The error or something is `\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi` by the way.

The other is `\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi`

EDIT2: So if boot into Ubuntu after picking "use another device" and then shut down and then turn the computer on later I get the Windows 7 boot selection. Ubuntu won't boot but Windows 8.1 will. After selecting Windows 8.1 I get the Windows 8 boot selection.

Why is it doing that? I don't understand!

Answer (score 1):

Open command prompt with administrative privileges form Windows 8.1. Type following command

```
bcdboot C:\Windows
```

C is drive letter where your Windows 8.1 is installed. If it is installed in any other drive replace the drive letter accordingly. Then reboot the system.

The above command replace the boot files with the ones from Windows 8.1

After the reboot if Ubuntu is missing from the bootloader use [EasyBCD](http://www.softpedia.com/progDownload/EasyBCD-Download-45820.html) and add entry for Ubuntu as Grub2 and leave all other fields to default and click Add entry.

Comment: The Windows 7 bootloader is gone now but the entry i just did doesnt work. Soooo close! The Select device works though. How could I make that one of the entries! Soooo close!

Comment: Nvm the windows 7 Boot selection still shows up. Only way to access the windows 8 boot selection is the shift method when u hold restart.

Comment: If you power on the system you get Windows 8 graphical boot manager with options to boot into Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu. If you select Windows 8.1 then Windows boots, but if you select Ubuntu you get an error.If this is true then follow this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). It will resolve most of the problem.

Comment: If above method doesn't work follow these steps. Open command prompt with administrative privileges. Type the following command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` This will replace Windows boot manager with Grub and Ubuntu will work fine.

Comment: Warning: if your Windows partition is encrypted this will ask for your BitLocker recovery key after rebooting!